# Does time dilation imply a determined Universe wherein the future already exists?

Tags: special-relativity

Temporal dilation or contraction that occurs at the relative motion between two objects, implies that the two objects are moving into the past and the future relative to each other.

A clock that is moving, ticks slower than a stationary clock. As I increase velocity on board a ship, I am temporally confined to the my observers past and my observer (as observed by me) moves into the future, as his clock ticks faster relative to my clock.

Therefore realtive to me, the future of my observer must already exist if indeed he can move into that future as his clock ticks faster than mine.

In this sense does time-dilation imply a determined view of the Universe in that: relatively speaking the future must already exist relative to me if I can observe my observer move into that future.

Comment: There is a grain of truth here about relativity - but the meaning of "time" in relativity is not what you think it is. When something "goes back in time" in relativity, it simply means it occurs earlier than it would have done relative to other events (and vice versa for moving forwards time). This is not the same as the flow of time as we perceive it (which is partly the flow of spatial movement as well as any movement of the relative timing of events).

Comment: Imagine you have one large clock with a large pendulum, along with two small atomic clocks. The two small atomic clocks are calibrated. One atomic clock is then mounted at the end of the large clocks pendulum. This large clock is also now calibrated via the use of the 2nd atomic clock. Over time, we see that due to the first small atomic clock having been swinging back and forth via mounted on the pendulum, this small clock indicates that less time has passed by when compared to the large clock, or the 2nd atomic clock. However, it is to be noted that all 3 clocks are still here in the "NOW".

Comment: What does "already exists" mean in this context?

Answer (score 1):

A basic principle of SR (special relativity) is that the laws of physics are the same in any IRF (inertial reference frame). That means that each of the two observers in relative motion will measure the other observer's clock ticking slower. A perfectly symmetric situation. In the question there is confusion with the twin paradox, when the twin leaving the earth comes back. In that case this latter changes reference frame in order to return to the earth, thus destroying the symmetry of the description.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding time dilation.  Two people moving relative to one another are not moving into the future or into the past relative to one another.  In simplest terms, your clocks are just going at different speeds.  So, while your clock might click 10 times and theirs clicks only 9 times, that doesn't mean they are 1 click of time in the past; their clock is just going slower.

It is more complicated than that; for example: from their point of view, your clock is the one going more slowly.

You are not living in their future and they are not in your past.  If something happens to them at 90 clicks, then it does not happen earlier for you because your clock is faster.  It happens when their clock hits 90 clicks, at which point yours will be at 100.  (And of course, they'll be so far away that it'll take a while longer for you to observe it).

And if something happens to you at 90 clicks on your clock, (when you observe theirs to be at 81), remember from their point of view your clock is the slow one, so they will observe (after subtracting for the time the light-took to travel to them) that it happened at 100 clicks on their clock.

None of this has anything to do with determinism.  Fundamentally, the argument is the same one that refutes "If it's already tomorrow in Australia, then that means the future has already happened."  One involves a shift in time zones, the other a change of time scale.

Answer (score -1):

Seemingly if a given event occurs (I click my fingers) then the extrapolation of SR, by the interpretation above, says that that moment in history would occur at different times for everybody depending on whether they are in motion. Whats more because they are in different motions their mass changes (which would change the value for Gravity making it potentially as much a function of motion as it is to mass). Producing a gravitational flux. Previously Einstein (in his review of the orbit of Mercury) postulated that the variance between the actual observation and the Newtonian calculation was due to the curvature of SpaceTime not the motion of the body. So i dont see how he can have it both ways.